# Java CompletableFuture threadpool used

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future, forkjoinpool

In the code below no matter what I set as the max value of i, the total number of threads never crosses 13. What thread pool does it use? Where can I find its default settings?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {

        System.out.println("kick off" + i);
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                System.out.println(java.lang.Thread.activeCount());
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("error");
            }
        });

    }
    System.out.println(java.lang.Thread.activeCount());
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How many processors has your computer? (`Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`)

Answer (score 15):

### Answer

It is determined either by your system settings or based on your current amount of processors.

---

### Documentation & Code

From the documentation of [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html):

> All `async` methods without an explicit Executor argument are performed using the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` (unless it does not support a parallelism level of at least two, in which case, a new Thread is created to run each task). This may be overridden for non-static methods in subclasses by defining method `defaultExecutor()`. [...]

From the documentation of [ForkJoinPool#commonPool()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool()):

> Returns the common pool instance. This pool is statically constructed; [...]

From the documentation of the class [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) itself:

> The parameters used to construct the common pool may be controlled by setting the following system properties:

> - `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism` - the parallelism level, a non-negative integer
> - `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.threadFactory` - the class name of a ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory. The system class loader is used to load this class.
> - `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.exceptionHandler` - the class name of a Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler. The system class loader is used to load this class.
> - `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.maximumSpares` - the maximum number of allowed extra threads to maintain target parallelism (default 256).

> If no thread factory is supplied via a system property, then the common pool uses a factory that uses the system class loader as the thread context class loader.

From there on, we have to check the actual source code. From [ForkJoinPool.java#L3208](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.java#L3208):

```
common = AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<>() {
    public ForkJoinPool run() {
        return new ForkJoinPool((byte)0); }});
```

From the constructor at [ForkJoinPool.java#L2345](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.java#L2345):

```
// [...]
String pp = System.getProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism");
// [...]
if (pp != null)
    parallelism = Integer.parseInt(pp);
// [...]
if (parallelism < 0 && // default 1 less than #cores
    (parallelism = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1) <= 0)
        parallelism = 1;
// [...]
int n = (parallelism > 1) ? parallelism - 1 : 1;
n |= n >>> 1; n |= n >>> 2; n |= n >>> 4; n |= n >>> 8; n |= n >>> 16;
n = (n + 1) << 1;
// [...]
this.workQueues = new WorkQueue[n];
```

And there you go. It is determined either by your system settings or based on your current amount of processors.

---

### Example math

Supposed you did not set anything for `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism`, lets quickly do the math for the code:

`parallelism` starts with `-1` in that case, so we have

```
if (parallelism < 0 && // default 1 less than #cores
    (parallelism = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1) <= 0)
        parallelism = 1;
```

Let us suppose you have 8 cores on your machine. So you execute `parallelism = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1` which assigns `7` to `parallelism`. You do not enter the `if`, so we continue.

Next up we have

```
int n = (parallelism > 1) ? parallelism - 1 : 1;
```

Which subtracts one of it, so `n = 6`.

Then

```
n |= n >>> 1; n |= n >>> 2; n |= n >>> 4; n |= n >>> 8; n |= n >>> 16;
n = (n + 1) << 1;
```

Results in `16`.

What this does is basically subtracting `2` and then going to the next power of `2` and then doubling it.

So if you have `6` cores, it goes to `4`, then to `8` and then times `2`, so `16`.

---

### So why 13?

So why do you get `13`? I suppose you have `4` or `5` processors, so the pool would use `8` threads. However, you are measuring the total amount of threads used by Java in total.

```
System.out.println(java.lang.Thread.activeCount());
```

And Java probably uses around `13 - 8 = 5` threads for other *"standby"* things right now.

Comment: Damn, how fast you are. And I wanted to wait for the OP to tell his processor amount so I can mention it in my answer.